# Вытащить из строки числовые слова

Tags: java

Нужно выбрать из строки только числовые слова.
Есть строка "45ggkjk 345 4g g7 43". И из неё нужно перенести в массив только 345 и 43.
Первое, что пришло в голову, сделать с помощью regex, что-то вроде такого "\s\d+". Но логично, что это не работает как нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выбора слов следует использовать границу слова `\b`:

```java
String s = "45ggkjk 345 4g g7 43";
Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b").matcher(s)
    .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
    .map(MatchResult::group) // Stream<String> подходящие числовые слова
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Результат:

```
345
43
```

Вместо `Stream::forEach` можно собрать результаты в список

```java
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

или преобразовать в массив:

```java
.toArray(String[]::new);
```